# Show or hide context menu item based on condition

Tags: sharepoint

How do I show or hide context menu items based on condition (For example, some item field value "True" or "False")? I`v added some custom actions for now (using features to add them), but would be nice to manipulate visibility of them.

[image]

I`m using WSS 3.0.

Thank you for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Out of the Box option Provided by SharePoint / WSS 3.0 to dictate the Visiblity of the menu Item other than below items

1. Permission of the user on the Item (Add /Edit etc)
2. GroupID or as configured in the Feature of SharePoint
3. Status of the Items (Approved/Check In)

Two option you can try out is to do some Java Script hack using jQuery to control the MenuItem Visibility else use the SPGridView but in this case you will need to create a New Menu altogether and Adding of Menu Items using Feature  is not possible.

Comment: Umm, well, I could go with javascript, only if there is a way to get SPListItem field value in javascript.

I wouldn't want to make a custom SPGridView for regular list.

Comment: Oh, you say "Status of the Items (Approved/Check In)". So sharepoint somehow reads SPListItem to determine the state.

This is my case, it's just I got a custom column with bool value.